# Why would the callback function on this Jquery animation be executing before the animation does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I have this javascript:

```
        $('.carouselItem.' + currentCarouselItem).animate({left: '975px'}, 'slow', function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).attr('style','');
            var nextItem = currentCarouselItem + 1;
            if (nextItem == 7) {
                nextItem = 1;
            }
            $('.carouselItem.' + nextItem).animate({left: '110px'}, 'slow', function(){
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
            }
        })
```

The callback on the first animation is executing before the first animation is complete. Any idea why?

Here is the full code if it would be more helpful:

```
var currentCarouselItem = 1; //set carousel to first slide
    var runCarousel = 1;
    var carouselInterupt = 0;


function autoScroll(){

        if (runCarousel == 1) {
            if (carouselInterupt == 0){

            $('.carouselItem.' + currentCarouselItem).animate({left: '975px'}, 'slow', function(){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).attr('style','');
                var nextItem = currentCarouselItem + 1;
                if (nextItem == 7) {
                    nextItem = 1;
                }
                $('.carouselItem.' + nextItem).animate({left: '110px'}, 'slow', function(){
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                });
                }
            })

            if (currentCarouselItem == 6) {
                currentCarouselItem = 1;
            } else {
                currentCarouselItem++;
            }

        }
    }

    setTimeout(autoScroll, 3000);

}

$(function(){

$(window).load(function(){

    autoScroll();

});

});
```

And here is the affected html (lots of lorem ipsum :) ):

```
    <div id= "wrapper">
    <div id= "teasertext" class="active carouselItem 1">


        <div class= "title"> <h1> Growing Your Business Online</h1> </div>

        <p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    <div id= "viewservices" class="teaserBttn"><a href="#" rel="#">View Services</a></div>


    </div>



    <div id= "about-teasertext" class="carouselItem 2">


        <div class= "about-title"> <h1> About</h1> </div>

        <p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    <div id= "view-about" class="teaserBttn"><a href="#" rel="#">View About</a></div>


    </div>



    <div id= "portfolio-teasertext" class="carouselItem 3">


        <div class= "portfolio-title"> <h1> Portfolio</h1> </div>

        <p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    <div id= "view-portfolio" class="teaserBttn"><a href="#" rel="#">View Portfolio</a></div>


    </div>



    <div id= "team-teasertext" class="carouselItem 4">

    <div class= "team-title"> <h1> Team</h1> </div>

        <p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    <div id= "view-teams" class="teaserBttn"><a href="#" rel="#">View Team</a></div>


    </div>



    <div id= "process-teasertext" class="carouselItem 5">
    <div class= "process-title"> <h1> Process</h1> </div>

        <p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    <div id= "view-process" class="teaserBttn"><a href="#" rel="#">View Process</a></div>


    </div>


    <div id= "packages-teasertext" class="carouselItem 6">
    <div class= "packages-title"> <h1> Packages</h1> </div>

        <p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    <div id= "view-packages" class="teaserBttn"><a href="#" rel="#">View Packages</a></div>


    </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an extra curly bracket `}`:

```
 $('.carouselItem.' + currentCarouselItem).animate({left: '975px'}, 'slow', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).attr('style','');
    var nextItem = currentCarouselItem + 1;
    if (nextItem == 7) {
      nextItem = 1;
    }
    $('.carouselItem.' + nextItem).animate({left: '110px'}, 'slow', function(){
       $(this).addClass('active');
     });
  }   //<----- HERE
  })
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  Was just about the post the same thing.

Comment: Ah... that definitely fixed some of it's strange behavior... Though it seems to keep running the second animate before the first is complete.

Comment: @chromedude can you post the affected html?